# Is there a constructive proof of Baer's Criterion?

Tags: reference-request, modules, constructive-mathematics, injective-modules

Baer's Criterion states than one can check injectivity of an $R$-module on inclusions of ideals. The proof, however, strikes me as very nonconstructive: it employs both Zorn's Lemma and LEM.

*Does someone know of a constructive proof of this theorem?*

I suspect it will involve some kind of restriction on $R$.

Comment: A trivial application already implies that all vector space are injective, which is not constructive at all. I wouldn't be surprised if it implied full choice in general.

Comment: What are some constructive examples of injective modules? (And which of several equivalent definitions should one take to be the constructively most appropriate one?)

Comment: Actually, my comment was a little too quick: it is not constructively valid that all ideal of a (geometric) field $k$ are $\{0\}$ or $k$, and the criterion involving "all ideals of $k$", is not that simple to prove...

Comment: @Andrej: It is [consistent with ZF](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1998165) that the zero module is the only injective module. Hence in some sense there can be no constructive examples. (However, if you believe in the existence of enough injective modules in the metatheory, then sheaf toposes over locales will also contain enough injective modules, see Theorem 3.8 of [this note](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.12708).) All the definitions of injective modules which I know are constructively equivalent. However, it might be possible to ponder a "dynamical variant". Daniel Wessel is the person to ask!

Comment: Addition a couple years later: It is worth noting that Baer's criterion does *not* require LEM, only Zorn's lemma. (Zorn's lemma and the axiom of choice are equivalent only iassuming LEM. Without LEM, AC implies Zorn but not the other way round.) This observation is good to know because while almost no topos validates Zorn+LEM (= AC), assuming Zorn in the metatheory, there is a plenitude of toposes which validate Zorn, namely at least the localic toposes.